# lambda client invoke function and read json messages from MQ and send to AWS Kinesis

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I have two lambda function written in python.

1- subscriber.py (Will connect to AWS MQ, collect and displays the message)

```
import time
import boto3
import stomp
import json
global message

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message in subscriber : "%s"' % message)
        invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="op_worker",
                                           InvocationType='Event',
                                           Payload=json.dumps(message)
                                           )
        #print('invoke_response a message in subscriber : "%s"' % invoke_response)
        print("terstesfsff")
        print (invoke_response['Payload'].read())
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[('b-4714-4441-8166-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
    lst = Listener()
    conn.set_listener('Listener', lst)
    conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[('b-4714-4441-8166-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
    conn.start()
    print('CONNECTION Started')
    conn.connect(login='test_mq', passcode='test_secure_mq',wait=True)
    print('CONNECTION established')
    conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/', id=1, ack='auto')
    print('CONNECTION Subscribed')
    time.sleep(10)
    conn.disconnect()
    return
```

2- worker.py (Which needs to collect message from subscriber.py function and pass this message to Kinesis)

```
import time
import boto3
import stomp
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #print (invoke_response['Payload'].read())
    print('received a message in worker : "%s"' % message)
    kinesis_client.put_record(
            StreamName='',
            Data=b'bytes',
            PartitionKey='1'
        )
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```

Error message while I am executing subscriber.py Lambda function:-

```
    Response:
null

Request ID:
"009406bc-f334-11e8-950f-fde41035f262"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 009406bc-f334-11e8-950f-fde41035f262 Version: $LATEST
CONNECTION Started
CONNECTION established
CONNECTION Subscribed
received a message in subscriber : "{

  "rateChange":{

    "contractCode":"DOPC/DOPC0004/W19",
    "sourceMarketGroup":"TNO"
}
}"
terstesfsff
b''
END RequestId: 009406bc-f334-11e8-950f-fde41035f262
REPORT RequestId: 009406bc-f334-11e8-950f-fde41035f262  Duration: 10255.69 ms   Billed Duration: 10300 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 33 MB
```

Error message on worker.py:-

```
    {
  "errorMessage": "name 'message' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/op_worker.py",
      12,
      "lambda_handler",
      "print('received a message in worker : \"%s\"' % message)"
    ]
```

[image: Subscriber Cloudwatch events]
Subscriber Cloudwatch events

[image: Worker Cloudwatch events]

Worker Cloudwatch events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

1. Your `subscriber.py` returns no error, but rather what is supposed to return. It returns `b''` as response from your `worker.py` call because `worker.py` yields no result
2. `worker.py` returns error because there's no variable called `message`. The json you send as function parameter when calling `worker.py` is inside the `event` object and you should access the information you are sending through `event`.

Comment: @AlexK- What should you think I need to do now. I am lost . Please suggest

Comment: First of all, I would suggest you print `event` in `worker.py` and see what is inside it. Then access whatever is needed, `event` is a dict so it is simple event['key_name'] call :) You can see an example here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html

Comment: Also, in order to see anything as `invoke_response` your `worker.py` **handler** should return `statusCode` and some value(s), all that in json format.

Comment: Heh, I have no idea what your code looks like now, but you have to return **json** object with `statusCode` but this is something for you to read on :)

Comment: You want me to write a copy/paste answer and you dont even read what I have posted. I told you there's no variable **message** defined and that you have to access your input data via **event** object.

Comment: Got it.. Thank you 

Comment: @AlexK- When I saw my Cloudwatch events, Json object which I sent in MQ is captured as a single message. I have attached cloud watch event screenshot. Please suggest

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue now

Comment: @AlexK-- I have sent JSON format message in my MQ, its not considering complete JSON message as a single message instead each value inside JSON as a message.

Comment: AlexK- I mean to say, my kinesis is in different AWS account, how can I put records connecting to it and send messages from Dev account to QA AWS account

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for worker:-

```
import time
import boto3
import stomp
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('received a message in worker : "%s"' % event)
    kinesis_client.put_record(
            StreamName='OnePurchasing',
            Data=b'bytes',
            PartitionKey='1'
        )
```